# trading view - how to save inputs per symbol

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have create a new indicator. But the inputs must be different for each symbol I select.

By example, imagine I want to create a custom Fibonaci, I wish to put it at different positions for every symbol. It is something we can do natively with the tools (long positions etc...).

So, I wish to have a set of inputs for every symbol, and not entering them each time I switch to another symbol, it drives my crazy :-P I have keep all the inputs in an excel sheet !

Do you know a solution for this?

Thanks

I can't find how to save the inputs per symbol. Even not sure it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the symbol with [syminfo.basecurrency](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_syminfo%7Bdot%7Dbasecurrency)

and with a [switch](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_switch), change the values of your script

Something like that:

```
value_0_382      = switch syminfo.basecurrency
    'BTC' => 0.382
    'ETH' => na
```

Comment: Thanks, I use a similar solution for now, but it requires custom code. I have requested this feature, but not sure it will come before years! We must be able to code some "tools" (in addition to indicators)